# Fill an array with a loop in BASH

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

I would like to fill an array automatically in bash like this one:

```
200 205 210 215 220 225 ... 4800
```

I tried with for like this:

```
for i in $(seq 200 5 4800);do
    array[$i-200]=$i;
done
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply:

```
array=( $( seq 200 5 4800 ) )
```

and you have your array ready.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `+=` operator:

```
for i in $(seq 200 5 4800); do
    array+=($i)
done
```

Answer (score 6):

Do it the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) way:

```
array=( {200..4800..5} )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have memory (or maximum length for a line) problems with those approaches, so here is another one:

```
# function that returns the value of the "array"
value () { # returns values of the virtual array for each index passed in parameter
   #you could add checks for non-integer, negative, etc
   while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
   do
      #you could add checks for non-integer, negative, etc
      printf "$(( ($1 - 1) * 5 + 200 ))"
      shift
      [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && printf " "
   done 
}
```

Used like this:

```
the_prompt$ echo "5th value is : $( value 5 )"
5th value is :  220

the_prompt$ echo "6th and 9th values are : $( value 6 9 )"
6th and 9th values are :  225 240
```